# Spring SingletonBeanFactoryLocator bean destruction

Tags: java, spring

While using `SingletonBeanFactoryLocator` and its `BeanFactoryReference` I found out that when I call `release` on `BeanFactoryReference` instance, some of the beans in the context are destroyed but some continue to live. My assumption was that all of them would be destroyed.

A consequence of this is, next time I use `SingletonBeanFactoryLocator` and `BeanFactoryReference` with same keys, instead of getting brand new beans, I get some beans carried on from the previous context. I'm not able to find a pattern behind this. These beans are singletons yet some of them are created anew and some of them carry on from old context. Why is it so?

Example:
let's say I have beans A, B and C in my context. All are singletons, B is injected in A and C is injected in B.

I get `BeanFactoryReference`, get these beans and then release `BeanFactoryReference`.

I then again get `BeanFactoryReference`; beans A and B are new but C is from old context (I printed their system hash codes to check it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue in Spring. It does clear all the beans. There was a glitch in the code using this which made it appear as though some beans were not destroyed but reused.